# Spritekit Multi-Node animation sequencer, can this be made more performant?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I needed to be able to sequence a set of SKActions operating on multiple nodes and wrote this test. It's easy to sequence multiple actions on a single node but there is no direct support to run sequences one after operating on multiple nodes (such as swap two nodes location then flash some other nodes then fade in some more nodes). The following code handles the sequencing, but I wonder if scanning all the nodes each `update` might take too much time if the number of nodes is too big.

```
class AnimatorSequence
{
    var animatorStack = [Animator]()
    var currentAnimator : Animator!

    func startAnimator()
    {
        currentAnimator = animatorStack.removeAtIndex(0)
        currentAnimator.execute()
    }

    func addAnimator( animator : Animator )
    {
        animatorStack.append(animator)
        if currentAnimator==nil && animatorStack.count == 1
        {
            startAnimator();
        }
    }

    func process()
    {
        if let anim = currentAnimator
        {
            if anim.isDone()
            {
                currentAnimator = nil
                if animatorStack.count > 0
                {
                    startAnimator();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

let animatorSequencer = AnimatorSequence()

class Animator
{
    typealias functionType = (() -> Void)?
    var function : functionType
    var parentNode : SKNode

    init (function:functionType, parent : SKNode)
    {
        self.function = function
        self.parentNode = parent
    }

    func execute()
    {
        if let f = function
        {
            f()
        }
    }

    func isDone() -> Bool
    {
        var count = parentNode.children.count
        for node in parentNode.children
        {
            if !node.hasActions()
            {
                count--;
            }
        }
        return count==0;
    }
}
```

example call:

```
    let a = Animator(function: { () -> Void in

        firstDot.node.runAction(moveToSecond)
        secondDot.node.runAction(moveToFirst)

        }
        , parent : self
    )

    animatorSequencer.addAnimator(a)
```

and each update

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
{
    animatorSequencer.process()
}
```

The point of this is to allow me to easily sequence a number of multiple-node animations with nothing more than a closure and not require anything complicated. It seems to work but I wonder if there is a more performant way to determine if all SKActions are complete.

Comment: Did you ever find a performant and cool way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote a class to do just what you are looking for. it is essentially a queue of SKActions that get called one after another. anything you add to the queue will be processed sequentially so you no longer have to worry about call back routines.  you can add actions from multiple different SKSpriteNodes without having to create action sequences.

https://github.com/evannnc/ActionQ